# High Sierra forgets display layout on reboot

Tags: macos, display, high-sierra

Since I upgraded to High Sierra, my 2-display layout gets reset to side-by-side every time I reboot, when instead it should be vertical to match the physical layout of my monitors.

While potentially unrelated, High Sierra also lost my Login Items after the upgrade.

I'm using a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017), running 10.13.

How can I get High Sierra to remember my display layout?

Comment: What model Mac are you using?

Comment: Good point. Added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your MBP uses Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM) to store various settings. It may be worth resetting this.

To reset the NVRAM on all Late-2016 and 2017 MacBook Pro models (with and without Touch Bar) follow these steps:

1. **Shut down your MBP.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.
3. Keep these keys pressed down for **at least 20 seconds!**
4. Let go of the keys and let your MBP reboot normally.

**Note 1:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Note 2:** If your Mac is using a firmware password, you will need to disable the firmware password before resetting NVRAM.

Comment: By firmware password do you mean the one I'm asked for before boot due to having FileVault enabled?

Comment: Refer to [How to set a firmware password on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455).

Comment: Thanks. I had this issue in Mojave. Though since I'm running a Hackintosh (custom PC) I ended up having to login into single-user mode, then running ```sudo nvram -c``` to clear it.

Comment: Didn't know that zapping the PRAM was still a thing!  Haven't seen that key combination in 20 years.

Comment: @Kaji Yep, that key combination has survived many iterations of the Macintosh operating system (although it's now referred to as NVRAM as opposed to PRAM). :)